# What does functional_qml_applicationName_matches_manifest mean?

Tags: application-development, qml

I submitted an application to the click store but it comes back with this error:-

```
functional_qml_applicationName_matches_manifest
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set applicationName in the main .qml file of your project, you need to set it to the namespace of your application. This could look like “com.ubuntu.developer.jbloggs.superapp” for example.

This will ensure that the app is working properly under confinement.

Comment: Is there a more technically accurate description of _why_ this needs to be? I don't see any need for this to be the case in the apparmor profile, and having it set to a human-readable name for the app seems to work fine on my phone, and gives a reasonable window title when running on my workstation under X11.